# Debug assertion failed for editing and deleting records

Tags: c

I am a relatively new programmer currently learning the `C language` at college. For my project I have been tasked to design a library system for students, I have been experiencing a `debug assertion failed`-error whenever I try to delete the same book that has been recently edited. Can somebody help me on this question?

PS: I have to submit the program in a few days' time, so I need some help! D:

Here's my code for editing books:

```
void EditBookInformation()
{
    int found = 0;
    char user_input[5];
    system("cls");
    printf("You have selected Edit Book Information \n");
    printf("Please enter the Book ID to edit the book: \n");
    scanf_s(" %s", &user_input, 5);
    fflush(stdin);
    fopen_s(&BookList, "record.txt", "rb+");
    fopen_s(&BookList2, "newrecord.txt", "wb+");
    fopen_s(&Logsheet, "log.txt", "a+");
    rewind(BookList);
    rewind(BookList2);
    while (fread(&Books, sizeof(Books), 1, BookList) != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(user_input, Books.Book_ID) == 0)
        {
            found = 1;
            printf("Book has been found! \n");
            printf("\nBook ID:%s \n", Books.Book_ID);
            printf("Title:%s \n", Books.Title);
            printf("Edition:%s \n", Books.Edition);
            printf("Year of publication:%s \n", Books.Year_of_publication);
            printf("Shelf location:%s \n", Books.Shelf_location);
            printf("Price in RM:%s \n", Books.Price);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            fwrite(&Books, sizeof(Books), 1, BookList2);
        }
    }

    if (!found)
    {
        printf("Book not found! \n");
        _fcloseall();
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        main();
    }

    char confirm;
    printf("\nDo you want to edit this book?");
    scanf_s("%c", &confirm);
    fflush(stdin);


    if (confirm == 'y')
    {
        printf("New Title:");
        scanf_s("%[^\n]s", &Books.Title, 50);
        while (getchar() != '\n');

        printf("New Edition:");
        scanf_s("%s", &Books.Edition, 6);
        while (getchar() != '\n');

        NewYearInput:
        printf("New Year of publication:");
        scanf_s("%s", &Books.Year_of_publication, 5);
        while (getchar() != '\n');
        int length = strlen(Books.Year_of_publication);
        int digit = 0;
        if (length == 4)
        {
            for (; digit < length; digit++)
            if (!isdigit(Books.Year_of_publication[digit]))
                break;
        }
        if (digit != 4)
        {
            printf("Wrong input! Please enter 4 digits for year! \n");
            system("pause>nul");
            goto NewYearInput;
        }

        printf("New Shelf Location:");
        scanf_s("%s", &Books.Shelf_location, 5);
        while (getchar() != '\n');

        printf("New Price in RM:");
        scanf_s("%s", &Books.Price, 5);
        while (getchar() != '\n');

        fprintf(Logsheet, "Book edited: %s \n", Books.Title);
        fseek(BookList, ftell(BookList) -sizeof(Books), SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(&Books, 1, sizeof(Books), BookList);
        fclose(BookList);
        fclose(Logsheet);
        printf("Book has been edited! \n");
        printf("Press any key to return to main menu \n");
        system("pause>nul");
        system("cls");
        main();
    }
    else if (confirm == 'n')
    {   
        printf("You have cancelled your operation! \n");
        _fcloseall();
        system("cls");
        main();
    }
}
```

And here is my code for deleting books:

```
void DeleteBookByBookID()
{
    int found = 0;
    char user_input1[5];
    system("cls");
    printf("You have selected Delete Book \n");
    printf("Please enter the Book ID that you want to delete the book \n");
    scanf_s("%s", &user_input1, 5);
    fflush(stdin);
    fopen_s(&BookList, "record.txt", "rb+");
    fopen_s(&BookList2, "newrecord.txt", "wb+");
    fopen_s(&Logsheet, "log.txt", "a+");

    rewind(BookList);
    rewind(BookList2);

    while (fread(&Books, sizeof(Books), 1, BookList) != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(user_input1, Books.Book_ID) == 0)
        {
            printf("Book found! \n");
            found = 1; 
        }
        else
        {
            fwrite(&Books, sizeof(Books), 1, BookList2);
        }
    }
    if (!found)
    {
        printf("Book ID not found! \n");
        _fcloseall();
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        main();
    }
    fclose(BookList);
    fclose(BookList2);

    char confirm;
    printf("Do you want to delete this book? \n");
    scanf_s(" %c", &confirm);
    fflush(stdin);

    if (confirm == 'y')
    {
        remove("record.txt");
        rename("newrecord.txt", "record.txt");
        fprintf(Logsheet, "Book deleted: %s \n", Books.Title);
        printf("Book has been deleted! \n");
        printf("Press any key to return to main menu \n");
        system("pause>nul");
        system("cls");
        main();
    }
    else if (confirm == 'n')
    {
        printf("You have cancelled your operation! \n");
        fclose(BookList);
        fclose(BookList2);
        system("cls");
        main();
    }
    fclose(Logsheet);
}
```

Comment: which IDE are you using? (like codeblocks, netbeans, etc...)

Comment: Well, did you step through the code in the debugger?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013, yes when I debug it his comes out.

Comment: This error only comes out when I edit the same book, the delete the same book afterwards

Comment: `scanf_s("%c", &confirm);` → `scanf_s(" %c", &confirm, 1);` and `scanf_s(" %s", &user_input, 5);` → `scanf_s("%s", user_input, 5);`

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the assertion ? Break into the debugger and look at the call stack.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but why are you calling `main();` from the `EditBookInformation` function ? This is __seriously wrong__.

Comment: Because I want it to return to the main menu after editing the book

Comment: Or if the book id is not found , it will return to the main menu

Comment: @ocsquare Look at Paul Ogilvie's answer and show your `main` if you want more advice.

Answer (score 0):

If a book is not found, you are calling `main`. But `main` should not be called by the user. It is called by the system and is the start of your program. Maybe you mean `return`?

You are reading from `BookList` and if the record read is not the one you want, you write it to `BookList2`. Once the record is found, you edit it and then write it to `BookList2` and then you close the files and rename the new file to the old file. But what happens to all the remaining records in the old file? Shouldn't you copy those too to the new file?

See also the comments to your post for other helpful sugestions.

Comment: Actually, my main() is my main menu, switch statements are used to select options like this for example

Comment: To prevent any confusion, link errors or other errors, NEVER call your function `main`.

Comment: Ahh I see, I'll try it tomorrow

Comment: Ps: Anything strange about my code? I just wanna confirm